# Reserve space on harddrive for application

Tags: c++, memory-management, storage

I have this application with which I would like to store about 50MB of data on the users hard drive. What I want to know is how I would be able to allocate(?) these 50MB so that it is considered used by the computer. My goal with this would be to make sure that if the user fills his/her hdd, my application still has 50MB of space to work with.

Any ideas or recomended approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a 50MB file on the HDD.   Use memory-mapped access.  Don't delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at memory mapped files. OS is probably more relevant than language.

Answer (score 1):

- Adapt your file format by adding a header, that contains the real
  file length
- On installation create a file of site 50MB filled with random data (to avoid sparsity) and a header saying 0 bytes used.
- When `fseek()`ing make sure you use your header length, not file length